# Hide only progressbar in uploadify

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, uploadify

I'm creating one web application using ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and Jquery .
Me use uploadify for uploading files from client and i want to upload file on post action of my form, so basically my problem is while i'm selecting file it shows progressbar with file list and uploading progressbar but i want to show only file not progress bar.
stuck at this point - Any suggestion ?

Comment: `Any suggestion ?` - Any code?

Comment: Dear Coder @DarinDimitrov i know you are very excited to give me answer,you can reply anything suggestion or code. everything is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a place to ask for code. StackOverflow is a place where you explain what you are trying to achieve, show the code you have tried so far to achieve the goal and explain the actual result. Only then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

so you don't need uploadify you just want multi file select
make form like this

```
 <form action="processThem.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" value="" name="upload[]" multiple>
      <button type="submit">Upload!</button>
 </form>
```

Square brackets in name of input type file are important also attribute multiple

see this post
http://www.hyperorg.com/blogger/2012/09/09/beginner2beginner-javascript-multi-file-upload-php-to-process-it/